# Google Endpoints V2 and Maven plugin version?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We have a multi-module (**war**-packaged) project that uses `com.google.appengine - appengine-maven-plugin` target being **ear** file.

We have migrated succesfully to Java8 and EndpointsV2. It builds and runs fine in Cloud. However the following requirement is still a bit questionmark in the migration instructions. What is the reason behind this incompatibility and requirement? Or is it just related to for example "discovery docs" that we are not using anyway?

> The old App Engine Maven plugin, with group com.google.appengine, is incompatible with the Endpoints Framework plugin. You must use the new version shown above

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using discovery docs or generated client libraries and are only using Endpoints as a library dependency, you can remove the Endpoints plugin and the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks @sayir yes we're not using discovery docs or generated libraries, what "Endpoints plugin" you're actually referring to?

The build goes fine, deploys and it works in cloud, but we still got email reminder from Google that we should migrate to Endpoints V2, just wondering for what reason... that's why I got suspicious about that incompatibility clause.

Comment: When did you migrate? The email is sent based on a week's worth of data, so if you migrated just before the email, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok, we deployed the migrated version (and removed all versions using EndpointsV1) May 29 and the reminder email came  June 4th.

Comment: @JariK were your doubts answered?, you should upvote the answer it helped you to clear the doubts.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if he totally answered your question, you should [accept his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), even if you can leave it just upvoted to see if someone else adds information.